# Does latest ios version gets updated on all the iphones

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I am thinking of learning ios development. I have a noob doubt- right now the latest ios is 13 so my doubt is whether the latest ios gets updated in all the iphones or not?
Basically, I want to learn which ios version centric app development should I learn- I have ios 12 and ios 13 in my mind.
p.s - I don't use iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Disclaimer: I have never written any app in Swift.</sup>

> .. whether the latest ios gets updated in all the iphones or not?..

It's upto the users to decide whether to update or not. As per this The Verge [article](https://www.theverge.com/2019/10/16/20918359/apple-iphone-11-pro-ios-13-adoption-rate-google-android-10), 50% of iOS users were using iOS 13 within three weeks of release. So clearly, many are using older versions either by choice, or due to  hardware incompatibility.

> .. which ios version centric app development should I learn ..

That might push the question a bit towards being primarily opinions based. Yes [iOS 13](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes) brought in a lot of new capabilities like

> ... build unparalleled augmented reality experiences with ARKit 3, Reality Composer, and RealityKit.

But being a beginner, I doubt that you should worry about that. You might want to keep track of Swift's release cycles.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/index.html

Answer (score 2):

- iOS 11–12 are supported on all iPhones since iPhone 5s (2013)
- iOS 13 is supported on all iPhones since iPhone 6s (2015)

Generally support is for n-1 from the latest major release of iOS. If you support iOS 12, you'll include every device since iPhone 5s. It's assumed people will be running the latest or n-1 version of iOS on their device.

[image]